# create new filetype with existing extension

Tags: command-line, extension, file-type

I made a Qt application, let's call it "alpha," that opens and generates `.zip` files. So basically, my files created by the app have the extension `.alpha` but they are basically `.zip` files. How do I associate `.alpha` files with my "alpha" application? Currently, by default, the `.alpha` files open with archive manager (because the system sees them as `.zip` files).

I looked at many possible solutions, with no success. I have tried the below methods:

1. I created a `alpha.xml` file in `/usr/share/mime/packages`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
       <mime-type type="application/alpha">
           <comment>ALPHA File</comment>
           <glob pattern="*.alpha"/>
       </mime-type>
   </mime-info>
   ```

   Now when I click `abc.alpha` file, I get an error saying:

   ```
   Could not display "abc.alpha". There is no application installed for "ALPHA File" files.
   ```
2. I edited the `/etc/mime.types` file to include the following line:

   ```
   application/alpha                zip
   ```
3. I created the file `alpha.desktop` - this works fine, as ALPHA is now shown in "open with other applications." However I still can't double click a `.alpha` file to open it in my program.

How do I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Archlinux default applications](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/default_applications):

1. Create your xml file in `~/.local/share/mime/packages` (I guess that `/usr/share/mime/packages` is also fine, but didn't test it)

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.local/share/mime/packages
   touch ~/.local/share/mime/packages/application-alpha.xml
   ```
2. Edit `application-alpha.xml`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
       <mime-type type="application/alpha">
           <comment>alpha file</comment>
           <glob-deleteall/>
           <glob pattern="*.alpha"/>
       </mime-type>
   </mime-info>
   ```
3. Now create the desktop file `~/.local/share/applications/alpha.desktop`:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Alpha
   Exec=/PATH/TO/YOUR/alpha
   MimeType=application/alpha
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   ```

   add the right exec path to your alpha application, and if this a console app change Terminal to true.
4. Now update the applications and mime database with:

   ```
   update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications
   update-mime-database    ~/.local/share/mime
   ```

Now if you double click your abc.alpha file `/PATH/TO/YOUR/alpha` app should open your file.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks. I had missed out adding "MimeType=application/alpha" in the alpha.desktop file

Comment: what does this line in the application-alpha.xml file do? <glob-deleteall/>

Comment: @akashrajkn glob-deleteall indicates that patterns from previously parsed directories must be discarded. The patterns defined in current file are used instead. From [here](https://developer.gnome.org/shared-mime-info-spec/). So you probably can also delete this line.

Comment: where should I place the image.svg for it to be used as an icon? I tried putting it in /usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/mimetypes, but the icon is not being shown